# SQL Server : Like Syntax and Add operator Error

Tags: sql-server, search, casting, binary

I am using this syntax and it should work well if only it doesn't get an error.

```
SELECT
   e.user_key,
   e.char_key,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring(e.char_data, 9, 16)) AS name,
   p.CHAR_DATA
FROM 
   CHAR_DATA0 AS e
INNER JOIN  
   CHAR_DATA1 AS p ON e.CHAR_KEY = p.CHAR_KEY
WHERE 
   p.CHAR_DATA LIKE '%'+CAST(cast(reverse(CONVERT(BINARY, 9998)) as BINARY(2)) AS BINARY(2))+'%'
ORDER BY 
   char_key
```

I need help. How to change this code for it to work?

`CHAR_DATA` column is of type `BINARY(2000)`

I have data like so: (got it using select)

```
 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
```

I need to search somewhere in those lines if it contains the entry I'm trying to find.

What I'm trying to find is always 2 bytes. So I'm looking for 0x0E27 in the syntax above.

This is a working syntax but its not what I want to do:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 37, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS helm 
FROM CHAR_DATA0 
WHERE CHAR_KEY = 5
```

Another this is if I use nvarchar(MAX) it gives results that doesn't even contain the data I'm trying to find.

Comment: I'd avoid doing this altogether by keeping those two bytes in a seperate field, if at all possible. Can you change the design of the CHAR_DATA1 table (I suspect not, just from the fact that it's name is "dodgy").

Comment: Sorry, but I can't change the design. I'm stuck with this very bad design that I need to workout. Please advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
where Convert(varChar(4000), CHAR_DATA,2 ) like '%' + Convert(varChar(4), CONVERT(BINARY(2), 9998),2 )+'%'
```

Comment: Of course!!! do the comparison in TEXT (not binary)... Bluddy obvious once you think of it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried just selecting that like clause, mainly because I don't need your schema (tables) to do so, and found a bug (I think) already:

```
SELECT '%' + CAST( CAST(REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY, 9998)) as BINARY(2)) AS BINARY(2) ) + '%'
```

produces:

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types varchar and binary are incompatible in the add operator.
```

... where as (changing the overal result type to varchar):

```
SELECT '%' + CAST( CAST(REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY, 9998)) as BINARY(2)) AS VARCHAR(2) ) + '%'
```

produces (we'll need some luck with the encoding here):

```
%'%    -- that is: percent, apostrophe, beam (the musical note), percent
```

Maybe that's the whole problem (though I doubt it)? Try it and let-is know how you go. I doubt it because I guess that if it was the whole problem then you would have worked it out for yourself from the error message (that I presume you would have gotten from SQL-Server).

Cheers. Keith.